# How to avoid unnecessary selects and joins in HQL and Criteria

Tags: hibernate, optimization, join, hql, criteria

I have been trying different combinations of **HQL** and **Criteria** and I haven't been able to avoid some unnecessary **joins** (in both) and some unnecessary **selects** (in Criteria).

In our scenario, we have a **@ManyToMany** relationship between **Segment** and **Application** entities (navigation is from Segment to Applications).

First I tried this **Criteria**:

```
Application app = ...
List<Segment> segments = session.createCriteria(Segment.class)
    .createCriteria(Segment.APPLICATIONS)
    .add(Restrictions.idEq(app.getId()))
    .list();
```

Wich produces this SQL:

```
select
    this_.id as id1_1_,
    this_.description as descript2_1_1_,
    this_.name as name1_1_,
    applicatio3_.segment_id as segment1_1_,
    applicatio1_.id as app2_,               <==== unnecessary APPLICATIONS columns
    applicatio1_.id as id7_0_,
    applicatio1_.name as name7_0_,
    applicatio1_.accountId as accountId7_0_,
    applicatio1_.applicationFlags as applicat5_7_0_,
    applicatio1_.description_ as descript6_7_0_,
from
    SEGMENTS this_ 
inner join
    SEGMENTS_APPLICATIONS applicatio3_ 
        on this_.id=applicatio3_.segment_id 
inner join                                       <==== unnecessary join
    APPLICATIONS applicatio1_ 
        on applicatio3_.app_id=applicatio1_.id 
where
    applicatio1_.id = ?
```

As you can see, *Criteria selects columns from APPLICATIONS*, which I don't want to be selected. I haven't found a way to do it (is it possible?). Also, it *joins with APPLICATIONS*, which I think is not necessary because the application id is already in the join table SEGMENTS_APPLICATIONS (the same happens with HQL).

(As an additional doubt, I'd like to know a Restriction that uses the app directly, and not app.getId(). As you will see, I could do that in the HQL version of the query)

Since I couldn't limit the select part (I don't need Application properties) I tried this **HQL** with the "select" clause:

```
Application app = ...
List<Segment> segments = session.createQuery(
    "select s from Segment s join s.applications as app where app = :app")
    .setParameter("app", app)
    .list();
```

wich produces:

```
select
    segment0_.id as id1_,
    segment0_.description as descript2_1_,
    segment0_.name as name1_,
from
    SEGMENTS segment0_ 
inner join
    SEGMENTS_APPLICATIONS applicatio1_ 
        on segment0_.id=applicatio1_.segment_id 
inner join                                        <==== unnecessary join
    APPLICATIONS applicatio2_ 
        on applicatio1_.app_id=applicatio2_.id 
where
    applicatio2_.id=?
```

You can see the *HQL doesn't select properties from Application* (thanks to the "select s" part), but *still joins the APPLICATIONS* table, which I think is unnecessary. How can we avoid that?

(As a side note, notice that in HQL I could use app directly, and not app.getId() like in the Criteria)

Can you please help me find a way to avoid "selects" in Criteria and unnecessary "joins" in both Criteria and HQL?

(This example is with @ManyToMany but I think it also happens with @OneToMany and also with @ManyToOne and @OneToOne, even with fetch = LAZY).

Thank you very much,
Ferran

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The additional selected columns when using Criteria come from a long-standing [bug in Hibernate](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3538). AFAIK, the only way to avoid it is to use HQL, or the JPA2 criteria API.

The other problem is also signalled as [a bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/JPA-19), but it has fewer impacts, and I wouldn't care much about it.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. A long-standing bug? I can't believe they haven't fixed it yet. Just because there is a workaround with HQL?

Comment: I can't believe it either :-( OTOH, it's open-source software, and they were probably busy implementing the new JPA2 criteria implementation, which should probably be preferred over this old proprietary API.

Comment: Oh, so would you recommend us to start using JPA2 instead of the old Criteria API? Can both be mixed? (Just to avoid refactorings of old code).

Comment: I don't recommend anything :-) But if I had to start a new project from scratch, I would use the standard JPA API and the new Criteria API.

Comment: @JB nizet Mentioning that bug has saved me a huge amount of head-scratching as to why a criteria query was uselessly left outer joining to a link table and slowing the query by an order of magnitude. HQL re-write it is!