# Optimize a query in hibernate with Criteria (avoid unnecessary joins)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have a class `A` which has another class `B` inside it. Something like this:

```
@Table(name = "A")
Class A {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
    B b;
}
```

I want to have a query like this:

```
SELECT * from A where B_ID = 4
```

But when I use `Criteria` to achieve my goal, it **inner joins** the two tables. How can I have a `SELECT` just as I said.

---

If it helps, I am having my Criteria like this:

```
DetachedCriteria crit = DetachedCriteria(A.class, "a");
crit.createAlias("a.b", "b");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("b.id", 4));
getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(crit);
```

Answer (score 2):

One to one relationships are eagerly fetched by default in Hibernate - that's why you're getting an inner join.  Try this:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
B b;
```

Comment: So you are saying that if I make the relation `LAZY`, the problem will be solved?

Comment: I would be very surprised if it doesn't solve the problem.  Hibernate should be smart enough to know that you're not wanting to load object B and that you just care about the ID which is stored on the table backing object A.

Comment: **This is SO NOT THE ANSWER**. I have set the relation to `LAZY` but, as long as there is a `createAlias` there is an `inner-join`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [How to avoid unnecessary selects and joins in HQL and Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665084/how-to-avoid-unnecessary-selects-and-joins-in-hql-and-criteria). It seems that it is a long-standing bug in Hibernate.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3538

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/JPA-19

This problem confuses me a lot either.